# etag with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, caching

I have a big JSON file accessible from `myapp.org/api/something` which is updated everyday at midnight. From this route I simply fetch some records from my database.

But as I know the records in that datbaase will only change once a day, I would like to tell my browser to use its cache to retrieve this resource.

So I would like to have:

- An expiration time of 12h from which the browser will simply use its cache
- Then an ETAG from which the browser will query the backend and perhaps get a 304 status code.

I am using the latest version of Laravel and I did not find any out-of-the-box information to manage resource cache.

How can I implement this with Laravel?

I have found this [middleware](https://github.com/matthewbdaly/laravel-etag-middleware) but I am sure a feature such as cache and 304 status code should be available with a vanilla installation of Laravel, am I wrong?

Comment: Are you doing server side caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into 3rd party libraries for caching. [Spatie/laravel-responsecache](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-responsecache) seems a good option at first glance. Alternatively you could implement it yourself, but that feels like reinventing something which other people probably solved already.